# Trying to call methods from another class

Tags: java

Hi everyone I'm new here and I'm new to Java.  I'm writing a program that plays a game of war and displays the game on a graphics panel.  I' having issues calling the draw methods from the Card class in the War class.  For example, when trying to use drawSpade I get the error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method drawSpade(Graphics, int, int) from the type Card".  I know there are tons of posts about this error but I'm having trouble understanding why it is happening in my program and how to fix it. Any help or advice would be great.  Thanks!

```
    public class War extends JFrame
    {

    private int card;
    private int drawNum;
    public int drawSuit;
    private final int xA = 225;
    private final int yA = 50;


    public War()
    {
        Color tableGreen = new Color(50, 150, 50);
        setBackground(tableGreen);      // Sets background color
        setSize(800,500);               // Sets window size
        setTitle("War");                // Sets window title
        setLocation(50,50);             // Sets where the window appears
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setVisible(true);               // Makes the window appear
    }

    int myCard()
    {
        Random myCard = new Random();
        return myCard.nextInt(13) + 1;
    }
    int mySuit()
    {
        Random mySuit = new Random();
        return mySuit.nextInt(4) + 1;
    }

    int compCard()
    {
        Random compCard = new Random();
        return compCard.nextInt(13) + 1;
    }
    int compSuit()
    {
        Random compSuit = new Random();
        return compSuit.nextInt(4) + 1;
    }


    public void cardNum()
    {
        if (myCard() == 1)
        {
            drawNum = 1;
        }
    }
    public void cardSuit()
    {
        if (mySuit() == 1)
        {
            drawSuit = 1;
        }
    }

    public void paint (Graphics pane)
    {
        drawSuit = 1;
        drawNum = 1;

        if (drawNum == 1)
            Card.drawBlank(pane, xA, yA);
            Card.drawTwo(pane, xA, yA);

        if (drawSuit == 1)
            Card.drawSpade(pane, 75, 100);

    }

     public int getDrawSuit() 
     {
         return drawSuit;
     }

}


    public class Card 
    {
    private static final int HEIGHT = 200;
    private static final int WIDTH = 150; 
    private final int xA = 225;
    private final int yA = 50;


    public void drawBlank (Graphics pane, int xA, int yA)
    {
        pane.setColor(Color.black); 
        pane.drawRoundRect(xA, yA, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 20, 20);
        pane.setColor(Color.white);
        pane.fillRoundRect(xA + 1, yA + 1, WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1, 20, 20);
    }
    public void drawSpade (Graphics pane, int xA, int yA)
    {
        pane.setColor(Color.black);
        Polygon triangle;
        triangle = new Polygon();
        triangle.addPoint(xA + WIDTH + WIDTH/2, yA + HEIGHT/5);
        triangle.addPoint(xA + WIDTH + WIDTH/2 + 5, yA + HEIGHT/3);
        triangle.addPoint(xA + WIDTH + WIDTH/2 - 5, yA + HEIGHT/3);
        pane.fillPolygon(triangle);
        pane.drawOval(xA + WIDTH + WIDTH/2, yA + HEIGHT/5, 20, 20);
        pane.fillOval(xA + WIDTH + WIDTH/2, yA + HEIGHT/5, 20, 20);
        pane.drawOval(xA + WIDTH + WIDTH/2 - 20, yA + HEIGHT/5, 20, 20);
        pane.fillOval(xA + WIDTH + WIDTH/2 - 20, yA + HEIGHT/5, 20, 20);
        pane.drawOval(xA + WIDTH + WIDTH/2 - 10, yA + HEIGHT/5 - 15, 20, 20);
        pane.fillOval(xA + WIDTH + WIDTH/2 - 10, yA + HEIGHT/5 - 15, 20, 20);
    }  
    /**
     * Numbers
     */
    public void drawTwo (Graphics pane, int xA, int yA)
    {
        if (getDrawSuit() == 1 || getDrawSuit() == 2)
            pane.setColor(Color.black);
        else
            pane.setColor(Color.red);

            pane.drawString("2", xA, yA);
    }

     public int getDrawSuit() 
     {
         return getDrawSuit();
     }
}
```

Comment: I see no static calls to `drawSpade()` in the code you posted. Are you calling it from somewhere else as well? Where is class `Card`?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `Card.drawSpade` which would be a static method of the class `Card`, but it doesn't exist.

`drawSpade` is declared as an instance method: `public void drawSpade (Graphics pane, int xA, int yA)`. If you want it to be a class method you need to declare as static. As it is, you need an instance of `Card`, e.g.

`Card c = new Card();
...
 c.drawSpade(pane, 75, 100);`

Answer (score 0):

In your example drawSpade is defined as non-static, meaning you need an INSTANCE of Card to be able to call it:

```
 private Card c = new Card();
 c.drawSpade(<arguments>);
```

If you want to call it as a static method, declare it as such with the static keyword:

```
public static void drawSpade (Graphics pane, int xA, int yA)
{
  ...
}
```

You can then call it as such:

```
Card.drawSpade(<arguments>);
```

Whether you need one or the other depends on what you use the method for. The static method does not keep a state for a Card, where an instance would have one and could be used to keep a state for every card in the game (by creating an instance for every card in the game).

Answer (score 0):

For this example we need to know the difference between a static method and a non-static method(aka instance method). When we create a static method were basically saying that this method now belongs to the class and that this method does not need to access an objects state.

so we would be able to just use the class name and then call the method.

```
 Card.drawSpade(pane, 75, 100);
```

however, since drawSpade is and instance method this means that we need to create and instance of that class in order to be able to call this method. We do this by creating an object generated from that class.

```
Card myCard = new Card();
myCard.drawSpade(pane,75,100);
```